# In C/C++, what's the minimum type up-casting required for mixed-type integer math?

Tags: c++

I have code that depends on data that is a mixture of uint16_t, int32_t / uint32_t and int64_t values. It also includes some larger bit shifted constants (e.g., 1<<23, even 1<<33).

In calculation of a int64_t value, if I carefully cast each sub-part (e.g., up-casting uint16_t values to int64_t) it works - if I don't, the calculations often go awry.

I end up with code that looks like this:

```
int64_t sensDT = (int64_t)sensD2-(int64_t)promV[PROM_C5]*(int64_t)(1<<8);
temperatureC = (double)((2000+sensDT*(int64_t)promV[PROM_C6]/(1<<23))/100.0);
```

I wonder, though, if my sprinkling of type casts here is too cluttered and too generous. I'm not sure the 1<<8 requires the cast (while despite not having one, 1<<23 doesn't lead to erroneous calculations) but perhaps they do too. How much is too much when it comes to up-casting values for a calculation like this?

Edit: So it's clear, I'm asking what the minimum proper amount of casting is - what's necessary for correct functionality (one can add more casts or modifiers for clarity, but from the compiler's perspective what's necessary to ensure correct calculations?)

Edit2: I'm using C-style casts as this is from an Arduino-type embedded code base (which itself used that style of casts already). From the perspective of having the desired effect they appear to be equivalent, thus I used the existing coding style.

Comment: What are the types of the other variables?

Comment: Why do you have extra parenthesis? This is not C.

Comment: "Too much" is a subjective opinion". "Not enough" is when the compiler is giving you warnings. "Too many" is when the code becomes unreadable. But using C-style casts is *definitely* wrong. This is C++, you should be using `static_cast` for numeric type conversions.

Comment: IMHO stuff like `1 << some_number` should be constant variables of the correct type so do not have to worry about them.  You just refer to the value by name.

Comment: @CodyGray I use C-style casts too when the meaning is unambiguous. It's just a matter of readability.

Comment: @MarkRansom yea `(int64_t)(1<<8)` is more readable than `int64_t(1<<8)` for sure

Comment: @Slava you make a good point, but that's not the choice I was making; it was between `(int64_t)(1<<8)` vs. `static_cast<int64_t>(1<<8)`.

Comment: This is Arduino-type  code, so I'm using what I'm used to in that context. Whether it's C-style or not shouldn't be making a difference to the output, should it? (And it's more compact, making it more readable than pure C++ style.)

Comment: @MarkRansom What does that mean? Can you give an example of an ambiguous C-style cast?

Comment: @Oktalist Hmm... the first thing that comes to mind is when it would be ambiguous what the desired C++-style cast is.  If a C cast could be read as either `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`, for example, that's when I consider it ambiguous.  Apart from that, when comparing C-style C casts and C++-style C casts, I guess it would be ambiguous when it isn't immediately obvious whether you're casting a value or calling a constructor.  `int(42)` is clearly a cast when used in an equation, while `MyInt(42)` might be either a cast or a ctor.

Comment: @Oktalist I don't mean ambiguous in terms of what the compiler would do, that's always well defined. I mean unambiguous in programmer intent.

Comment: 3 votes to close this? Is it that bad of a question? My goal here is to ensure that all lesser types in a given calculation are promoted to the type of the result - which I thought *might* be something the compiler would see and automatically work with (if the result is int64, the intermediates ought to be upcast to that as needed). Since that's not what happens I wanted to ensure I only added enough casting for it to work, and possibly beyond that for readability sake. Thus this question.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but "how much is too much" sounds like a opinion question. Perhaps change the title to something like "what's the minimum amount of casts needed here".

Comment: @Oktalist - Thanks! Updated title.

Comment: @Mark I see where you're coming from, but I feel like C-style casts are just too powerful, considering the reality that code evolves over time. It would be too easy to hide a mistake. Plus, any time I see a C-style cast, my brain raises a yellow caution flag, much like a reinterpret_cast, so they aren't necessarily more readable for me. With appropriate use of whitespace, I find it can usually be done without sacrificing readability. Maybe I'm just weird, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally you can rely on the integer promotions to give you the correct operation, *as long as one of the operands for each operator have the correct size*. So your first example could be simplified:

```
int64_t sensDT = sensD2-(int64_t)promV[PROM_C5]*(1<<8);
```

Be careful to consider the precedence rules to know what order the operators will be applied!

You might run into trouble if you're mixing signed and unsigned types of the same size, although either should promote to a larger signed type.

You need to be careful with constants, because without any decoration those will be the default integer size and signed.  `1<<8` won't be a problem, but `1<<35` probably will; you need `1LL<<35`.

When in doubt, a few extra casts or parentheses won't hurt.

Comment: Or `int64_t(1) << 35` tbh

Comment: I'm surprised this question generated so much controversy. So, in the case of a+b+c+d, where the output is to an int64_t and [a..d] are all int32_t, I'd want to cast, at minimum, "b" and "d" to int64_t? Or would casting just one suffice (say "a", as a+b will then be int64_t in the sum (a+b)+c, and so on)? It's not about opinion but minimum accurate representation - I would likely add more casts for visual clarity.

Comment: @MartyMacGyver: You'd only need to cast one, as in your second example. Normally when expressions get confusing, one would do the cast _as a separate variable via `static_cast`, which makes it blatantly clear what you're casting and that it's needed.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that the type of the result itself doesn't factor in, but clearly it doesn't. I appreciate the explanation.

Comment: @MartyMacGyver the computation and assignment are completely independent operations, so the assignment has no impact on the computation. You can even leave out the assignment altogether, so that the calculation goes to a temporary result that is never used! A good compiler will recognize that it's dead code and optimize it out, but the syntax still allows it. It's the same reason that the return type of a function isn't part of the overload resolution.