# Typecasting from int to long int

Tags: c++, int, long-integer, typecasting-operator

Recently I searched the difference between `int`, `long int`, `long`, ... and so on. And I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971732/what-is-the-difference-between-long-long-long-long-int-and-long-long-i). And I found that `long` and `long int` are identical. So the statements
`c = a *long(b);`

and

`c = a * long int (b)`

should be same in the program

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 20;
    long int c;
    
    c = a *long(b);
    cout << c;
    
    return 0;   
}
```

But the second statement is showing an error

**[Error] expected primary-expression before 'long'**

So I just want to know, if `long` and `long int` are identical, so why there is error in the above two statements ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're running the wrong code lol

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, the OP fooled me :-P ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because they are the same type doesn't mean you can literally exchange the characters in your source code.

The syntax is confused by a `T()` cast when `T` has a space in it.

Write `c = a * (long int)b` instead.

Comment: Good one. Should mention that `(long int)` is the C-way while `static_cast<long int>` is the C++ one.

Comment: @Benoit: Both are valid in C++.

Comment: You seem really experienced in c++. I wonder what do you mean by 'valid'. Working ? Acceptable ? or perfectly suitable ? All references that i found said 'do not use C-like cast in c++'. I can't open a question because it will be tagged as duplicate but i read a lot of your posts and i am really curious about your opinion on that.

Comment: @Benoit: It's not vastly idiomatic, particularly for complex types, but it's completely fine for an arithmetic type as far as I'm concerned. Some people will insist on `static_cast` for absolutely everything but in this case it's unnecessarily verbose. In fact this came up just the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37996003/560648

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly the kind of explanation and 'fight' I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets for this.
eg.

```
c = a * (long int) (b)
```

As type casted data type have multi-words.

Comment: This is already covered in the previous answer.